# How to make AngularUI sortable connect lists in different divs?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I'm trying to get AngularUI sortable connect two lists located in separate divs.

Can someone please explain what the issue is and why one method works and the other doesn't ? and what I need to do to fix it ?

I did get the lists connected if the divs are both siblings of the element defining the sortable:

```
<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-repeat="list in modelData" ng-model="list" class="sort">
    <div id="item-list" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaryM/PHvVS/

This is the method I need to work:

```
<div class="sortSrc"  style="display:inline;">
    <ol ui-sortable="srcSortableOptions" ng-model="srcData">
        <li ng-repeat="item in srcData">{{item}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="sortTgt"  style="display:inline;">
    <ol ui-sortable="tgtSortableOptions" ng-model="tgtData">
        <li ng-repeat="item in tgtData">{{item}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaryM/2AnLU/

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove parent divs for ol's. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5MKwS/) works just fine

Please see the [refer](http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/uFile) how they do in official github of ui-sortable

```
<div>
  <ol ui-sortable="srcSortableOptions" ng-model="srcData" class="sortSrc"  style="display:inline;">
    <li ng-repeat="item in srcData">{{item}}</li>
  </ol>
  <ol ui-sortable="tgtSortableOptions" ng-model="tgtData" class="sortTgt"  style="display:inline;">
    <li ng-repeat="item in tgtData">{{item}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! I am a bit confused to why the div is handled differently than the ol element.. The official demo on github you referred uses <div> as elements.   The reason for the question is I need to place the sortables in a jquery layout.. let me place with this a bit and post another comment here..

Comment: Just tried replacing the div with ol element in the jquery layout, it works !! Again thank you..

Comment: I see what they did, the directive requires to have the elements as siblings and not separated by other elements. I'll fork the directive and try to make it work with arbitrary elements.